# Sentry Clojure integration, Sentry is not receiving alerts. Network/queue error

Tags: clojure, backend, sentry

I have a Clojure backend integrated with Sentry running in a pod. I noticed that I am not receiving any Sentry alerts on the panel. To investigate further, I connected to my REPL and performed a simple test. I ran the following code snippet:

```
`clj꞉myapp.core꞉> (sentry/send-event (Exception. "testing") "testing!!" )

-->> "dda4a47f31eb48bbb0992a1651c8edca"
```

I received the expected behavior, as I obtained the event ID. However, when I reviewed the pod logs, I discovered the following error message:

```
"fingerprint": [],
    "modules": {},
    "event_id": "dda4a47f31eb48bbb0992a1651c8edca",
    "contexts": {
        "runtime": {
            "name": "Eclipse Adoptium",
            "version": "17.0.6"
        }
    },
    "sdk": {
        "name": "sentry.java",
        "version": "6.13.0",

...

DEBUG: Serializing object: {
    "timestamp": "2023-04-26T19:11:02.289Z",
    "discarded_events": [
        {
            "reason": "queue_overflow",
            "category": "error",
            "quantity": 480
        },
        {
            "reason": "network_error",
            "category": "error",
            "quantity": 720
        }
    ]
}
DEBUG: Envelope sent successfully.
DEBUG: Envelope flushed
```

I checked the DSN and is okay.

I double checked the dsn env var

Answer (score 4):

`network_error` means the SDK wasn't able to send the event to Sentry.

We can see a couple of places where this can happen in the code:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/308cdb2687e591e30440c00d2b0c27d4570e80c2/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/transport/AsyncHttpTransport.java#L263

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/blob/308cdb2687e591e30440c00d2b0c27d4570e80c2/sentry/src/main/java/io/sentry/transport/AsyncHttpTransport.java#L281

Basically the server returning 4xx (except 429 which is Too Many Request (aka rate limiting)) or a network error. Is it possible your server had no connectivity to Sentry? A firewall or proxy blocking it?

`queue_overflow` means the in-memory queue, which is capped by 30 items by default, was reached. So the SDK started load-shedding by discarding any new attempt to queue an event.

```
DEBUG: Envelope sent successfully.
DEBUG: Envelope flushed
```

That indicates an envelope was successfully sent but that [could be just the `client_reports`](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/client-reports/) which are these dropped metrics.

If you on [the stats page in Sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/product/stats/), what does it say there? Are all events just dropped?

Are you using a self-hosted version of Sentry that's very old? Envelope support was added in Sentry `20.06`, and client reports on `21.09`.